# Haskell Data.Decimal as Aeson type

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Is it possible to parse a [Data.Decimal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.4.2/docs/Data-Decimal.html) from JSON using the Aeson package?

Suppose I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "foo": 5.231,
    "bar": "smth"
}
```

And the following record type:

```
data test { foo :: Data.Decimal
          , bar :: String } deriving Generic
```

with

```
instance FromJSON test
instance ToJSON test
```

This would work, if it weren't for the `Data.Decimal` value "foo".

From what I understand I would need to manually create a `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` (for converting back to JSON) instance of Data.Decimal, since it doesn't derive from Generic. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might wrap `Decimal` in a `newtype` (to avoid writing an orphan instance) and then follow the [Writing instances by hand](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:2) section of the *aeson* documentation. In all likelihood, however, the sensible thing to do is switching from `Data.Decimal` to `Data.Scientific` (from the [*scientific*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.4.9) package), which does have instances provided by *aeson*.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I switched to Data.Scientific

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but might help someone. Here is how I am converting Decimal to/from json (I assembled this code from a bunch of other code which I don't have the source for now):

```
instance A.ToJSON (DecimalRaw Integer) where
  -- maybe this is not the best, but it works
  toJSON d = A.toJSON $ show d

instance A.FromJSON (DecimalRaw Integer) where
  parseJSON = A.withText "Decimal" (go . (read :: String -> [(DecimalRaw Integer, String)]) . T.unpack)
    where
      go [(v, [])] = return v
      go (_ : xs) = go xs
      go _ = fail "Could not parse number"
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. First you should use reads function instead of read, second the case go (_ : xs) should also result in a failure, not a recursive call.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using
parseJSON = A.withScientific "Decimal" (return . right . eitherFromRational . toRational)
and it works fine