# Haskell Aeson - Gloss - JSON instance parser: Color

Tags: json, haskell, types, instance, aeson

We are trying to decode a JSON object using the [Aeson-JSON](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html) hackage using the following data:

```
data Car = Car
  { carPosition  :: Position,
    carColor     :: Color,
    carDirection :: Direction }
  deriving (Show, Generic)
```

Created an instance for `Car`, and did the same for the data types `Postion`, `Direction`:

```
instance FromJSON Position
instance FromJSON Direction
instance FromJSON Car
```

But now the trouble starts, the data type [`Color`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.1.1.0/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Color.html) comes from the [`Gloss`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) hackage and the value is e.g. written as [Red](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.1.1.0/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Color.html). The `Color` data only knows: `deriving Show`, so no possibility of adding the `deriving Generic`. We tried the following code:

```
instance FromJSON Color where
      parseJSON (Object v) = Color <$>
        v .: "carColor"
```

It complains about not matching type `Picture -> Picture` and we expected something like `Color`.

Our question is: how can we use the data `Color` from `Gloss` to read a JSON object like

`{ 
  "carPostion": { "x": 0, "y": 10}, 
  "carColor": "Red", 
  "carDirection": "Up"
}`

We have tried to read a JSON object without `carColor` (just for testing purposes) and that works.

UPDATE: It looks like this question: [Haskell Data.Decimal as Aeson type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331851/haskell-data-decimal-as-aeson-type) except in our case we want to use `Color` where in the given like `Data.Decimal` is the trouble maker.

Comment: What does `Color` looks like? Furthermore it does not make much sense for me that you parse this that way. I would explect `parseJSON` to parse a JSON string, or something equivalent.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated my question. The main problem is `Color`, without this property we can successfully read a JSON object with the given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to parse base strings, this is pretty simple:

```
instance FromJSON Color where
  parseJSON (String s) = maybe mzero return $ stringToColor s 
  parseJSON _ = mzero


stringToColor :: String -> Maybe Color
stringToColor s 
  | s == "red" = Just red
  | s == "blue" = Just blue 
  ... -- fill in all of your options from Gloss
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

This allows you to turn a simple string into one of your `Color` objects. Once you have the `FromJSON` instance for `Color`, you can just use `instance FromJSON Car`.

Comment: Thank you, I guess there is no direct way to do this (without converting from a string to a color). Anyway, this solves pur problem :)